# How to assign id to quasar input validation error message?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I want to check with Selenium test if the error message appears under my q-input or not, for this I would need it to have an id, so I can find the Webelement:

```
 <q-input v-model="emailInput" 
      :rules="[(val) => validateEmail(val) || 'Valós email címet adj meg.']"
      for="username" label="Email" square type="email">  
 </q-input>
```

This looks like this then:
[image]

All I want is to add an id somehow to this div that has role="alert" to be able to get it text and assert.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [slot for error messages](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#example--slot-for-error-message) to the q-input and add id to your own custom alert element

```html
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh">
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
    <q-input
      ref="inputRef"
      v-model="model"
      filled
      label="Type here"
      hint="Max 3 characters"
      bottom-slots
      :error="!isValid"
    >
      <template #error>
        <div id="error-alert">custom error message</div>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/NWOMwmR?editors=1010)

Alternatively, you could select the q-input by id and then xpath to the child alert element.